# Primitive object size in java/scala and 'as<SomePrimitive>Buffer() methods invocation

Tags: java, scala, dynamic, reflection, primitive-types

My objective is generalize shapes creation from Android OpenGL ES tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/shapes.html
It looks like this right now:

```
val squareCoords = Array( -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
  -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
  0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f ) // top right

val vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
  // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
  squareCoords.length * 4)
  .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
  .asFloatBuffer()
  .put(squareCoords)
  .position(0)
```

So, float size is hardcoded.
But I have some Short arrays too:

```
val drawOrder = Array[Short] ( 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ) 
val drawListBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
  // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
  drawOrder.length * 2)
.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
.asShortBuffer()
drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder)
drawListBuffer.position(0)
```

Code looks similar but challenge part is to choose right method asFloatBuffer()/asShortBuffer() in this case and use right primitive value.

I wrote this code to resolve this issue:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

implicit class SByteBuffer[T <: AnyVal : TypeTag] (coords: Array[T]) {
  private val length = coords.length
  def buffer(): Buffer = {

    def allocateBb(mod: Int) = {
      ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(length * mod)
      .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
    }
    val buffer = typeOf[T] match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Float] => allocateBb(4).asFloatBuffer().put(coords.asInstanceOf[Array[Float]])
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Short] => allocateBb(2).asShortBuffer().put(coords.asInstanceOf[Array[Short]])
    }
    buffer.position(0) 
  }
} 

val squareCoords = Array( -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
  -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
  0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f ) // top right

val vertexBuffer = squareCoords.buffer()
```

But it seems too complicated and there is code repeats.
Can you advice how to refactor this code to look more concise and possibly get rid of runtime type checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be better off creating separate implicit classes for each primitive type that you want to support:

```
abstract class ArrayOpsBase[T <: AnyVal] ( val coords: Array[T] ) {
  protected val length = coords.length
  protected def allocateBb(mod: Int) = {
    ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(length * mod)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
  }
  def buffer(): Buffer
}

implicit class FloatArrayBufferOps( coords: Array[Float] ) extends ArrayOpsBase[Float]( coords ) {
  def buffer = allocateBb(4).asFloatBuffer.put( coords ).position( 0 )
}
implicit class ShortArrayBufferOps( coords: Array[Short] ) extends ArrayOpsBase[Short]( coords ) {
  def buffer = allocateBb(2).asShortBuffer.put( coords ).position( 0 )
}
```